# When using advanced search in Galaxybase, what kind of indexing should be established for attributes?

Tags: full-text-search

When using Galaxybase graph database and wanting to perform advanced searches on the visualization interface, i want to search based on attributes using Cypher query language, which choose between simple indexing, composite indexing, or full-text indexing，may i should?

I tried a simple indexing approach, but I didn't retrieve any results.